# WebViewClient to allow more then one domain

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I have a webview which I restrict to a specific domain, so the user won't try to go from there to other domains.

One of my fragments loading a url from one domain and need to transfer to other domain when click on a button in the site.
So I tried to come up with the logic to allow this:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
private String firstUrl, secondUrl;

public MyWebViewClient(String firstUrl, String secondUrl) {
    this.firstUrl = firstUrl;
    this.secondUrl = secondUrl;
}
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains(firstUrl) == true && url.contains(secondUrl) == true) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;

}
```

}

Which is not working, the site is loading fine but when trying to press the link for the second approved URL, it's just not loading it...

any solutions/ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the if statment `if (url.contains(firstUrl) == true && url.contains(secondUrl) == true)` you are checking if the url pertains to the two domains at the same time, wich is impossible. You are also always returning `true`, so WebView will override url loading

Here is how the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` must look like:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains(firstUrl) || url.contains(secondUrl)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi,
Already fixed it, just didn't updated the post.
Sorry and thank you for the answer.